# DateTime saved wrong in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a column called `CreateDate` (DateTime) in `table1` in SQL Server 2008.

With a stored procedure I try to update `CreateDate` as parameter, like this:

```
SqlParameter spdtCreateDate = cmd.Parameters.Add("@dtDreateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
spdtCreateDate.Value = dtCreateDate;
```

From an application in C# I send `CreateDate='6/29/2012 12:00:00 AM'` but when I check in database the `CreateDate` is set as `2012-06-28 23:00:00.000` instead as `2012-06-29 00:00:00.000`

Can anyone tell me what happen?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Should you not be expecting 2012-06-29 12:00:00? As the data type is DateTime which accounts for the hours and minutes. I would recommend running the profiler against the database and see what value is being sent.

Comment: Have you stepped through the C# code and established exactly what value is in dtCreateDate at the point where you assign it to the parameter?

Comment: @DarrenDavies - Note that mid-day (As in your comment) is 12:00`pm` not `am`.  Midnight is considered the start of a day (not the end) and is 12:00`am` in 12 hour clock.  So, what the OP expects eems to make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server `datetime` type does not include any time zone information. Because of this, the SQL Server client libraries assume that you will always want to store local times in it. If you have set your .NET `DateTime` value to something with the UTC time zone, then the SQL Server client will helpfully convert it to local time for you before storing it.

Possible solutions:

- Change your .NET `DateTime` value to specify `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` or `DateTimeKind.Local`.
- Change the table column and sproc parameter data types to `datetimeoffset` (SQL 2008 or above).

Comment: It's true that SQL Server doesn't store timezone information, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't convert parameters from UTC to local.  Do you have a reference for this behavior?